# HTML in Russian

Tags: html, utf-8, dreamweaver, cyrillic

I have to design a Russian version of a web. I get the text from a translator. I copy it in the code of the Dreamweaver but it doesn't work.

I have the usual head:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
```

What should I do?

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean? Can you see it in the dreamweaver but not on the page after reloading or neither in the dreamweaver nor on the page? Make sure you save your file in the coding that allow to use Russian alphabet.

Comment: When I say that it don't works I mean that I cannot see the letters well. Here it is: http://www.mig-marketing.com/proves/nando/ru/ I know nothing about Russian but it's clear that the letters have changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying so many tings I discovered that the problem was in the server. I don't know exacly how, but when I told them that I need a web in russian they changed something and it works!.

Answer (score 9):

You should change encoding of your file to UTF-8. You can do this process when you **Save As** file in Notepad or you can use [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/)(**Encoding -> Encode in UTF-8**) for it.

Comment: I don't understand your answer. As you can see the question I put the UTF-8 in the head. I have a mac and I think Notepad ++ is just for pc.

Comment: Meta tag with charset tells only that what is in the file is in utf8. But if you save file as iso-8859-1 and tell browser that it is utf8 then you will get something like this.

Answer (score 3):

The document http://www.mig-marketing.com/proves/nando/ru/ contains Russian text in an image only, but it links to http://www.mig-marketing.com/proves/nando/ru/firma.html which contains (in addition to text in an image) Russian text in ISO-8859-5 (= ISO Latin/Cyrillic) encoding. This encoding is declared in a `meta` tag, but the problem is that the declaration has no effect, since HTTP headers take preference over them, and they say

```
Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1
```

(You can conveniently check the HTTP response headers using Firefox with Web Developer Extension and selecting Information → View Response Headers.)

To fix this, contact the web server admin or try and fix it yourself, if the Apache settings allow the use of per-directory `.htaccess` files, in which case just create a file with that name (including the leading dot) in the directory containing the Russian files and enter the text

```
AddType text/html;charset=ISO-8859-5 html
```

This would then make the server send all .html files in that directory with HTTP headers that specify them as ISO-8859-5 encoded.

Answer (score 2):

Re-save all your files in UTF8 forcefully.

Comment: I have mac, so I cannot use notepad. I tried with TextWrangler. 1- I paste a paragraf. 2. Save as > Encoding Unicode(UTF-(8) 3. This is the output: http://www.mig-marketing.com/proves/rus/textWrangler.html

Comment: @Narcís: Seems that the source is already broken, so saving in UTF doesn't fix the problem. Do you have a correct source? How do you type in Russian?

Comment: I have no idea of Russian. So, I sent the text to a translator, she send me back a word with two columns: one in my language and another in russian (to identify each part). So I first copy-paste in Dreamweaver. Second time copy paste in TextEdit (similar to NotePad in mac) Save as .txt utf-8 and then copy paste to TextWrangler. (I of course have no keyboard and no knowledge to type directly in Russian in the code editor. I have to copy paste from what the translator send me)

Comment: @Narcís: Then word doc should be in proper encoding already. So copy-pasting from word to any editor breaks encoding, right? Try to ask the translator to send you properly saved text file maybe?