# Incorrect http header field value encoding

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs, http, encoding, http-headers

I use `Response.Headers.Add()` to add custom header. Header value contains russian text.
Fiddler shows text correctly but AngularJs returns header text as it was encoded as Win1251.
However, header for charset is set to utf-8

Tested this behavior in IE11 and Chrome

Original text:

> Данные были изменены пользователем

Shown text:

> Р”Р°РЅРЅС‹Рµ Р±С‹Р»Рё РёР·РјРµРЅРµРЅС‹ РїРѕР»СЊР·РѕРІР°С‚РµР»РµРј

I have no idea why this happens. Any thought how can I fix this?

Comment: This answer may help you http://stackoverflow.com/a/8699025/713789

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no default character encoding for header fields. If you use non-ASCII characters, you're on your own. I'd recommend to use escaping, such as URI encoding, or the encoding defined in RFC 5987.

Comment: That worked. I encoded text as uri component and then used decodeUriComponent() function in JS. Many, many, Thanks!

Comment: @Julian - Thanks for the update. I didn't realize the RFC 723X specs had made it out of draft finally (as of 2 months ago).